# Tag merge request: [urlfetch] and [urlfetchapp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

While doing a cleanup of my older posts, I noticed that there is a tag that duplicates the already established one that we use to tag questions about both `UrlFetchApp` [service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) in Google Apps Script and the App Engine infrastructure.

The established [urlfetch](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/info) tag has a wiki and [a lot of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlfetch?tab=Newest) questions (441 at the time of writing).

The [urlfetchapp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetchapp/info) tag has no wiki and only a [handful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlfetchapp) (21 ATTOW) of questions. Additionally, I would argue that its application is too narrow to warrant a separate tag (we don't have `SpreadsheetApp` tags, etc for that reason).

I propose merging them or at least making the latter a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/synonyms) of the first.

Comment: I would go for the synonym if there is no question mis-tagged in those 21 questions.

Comment: @rene - I don't see any mistagged, so I totally argee that a synonymizing may be enough. Just need to point out that this tag is inconsistent with how "[service name]App" are treated (there are [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriptapp+or+documentapp+or+spreadsheetapp+or+formapp+or+contactsapp) for others)

Comment: I somehow missed this when it was first posted. I've merged the tags and created the synonym now.

Comment: @CodyGray - thank you! I wish tag suggestions were more visible than "in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet" to not bother moderators to do it manually :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been complaining about the limitations with tag synonym suggestions for [literally years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag/103213#103213). All I can do is try to watch out for reasonable suggestions made on Meta and action them as I get a chance. Some of them slip under my radar. Honestly, I would *rather* have subject-matter experts making these decisions than moderators.

Comment: @CodyGray - holy mother, that's how long ago the debate goes?! Even a small change in visibility would've helped, but alas. Thank you for keeping track of these - it is nearly impossible to push (not counting the retagging workaround) unless someone looks out for retag requests... Seems like posting an answer works in case this happens helps a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started a process of synonymizing the two tags as I came to conclusion that [urlfetchapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlfetchapp) tag is indeed harmless and is useful in case the asker is only aware of the `UrlFetchApp` built-in service. There is now a pending there is now a pending suggestion for [making [tag:urlfetchapp] a synonym of [tag:urlfetch]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/synonyms).

Please, do vote for synonymizing if you agree and have enough reputation in the tag ands priviledge to vote.